# How long a latest rack server in data center takes to boot?

Tags: time, datacenter, start

For an short/simple experiments, I need to know how long a latest rack server Xen/Vmware hypervisor installed with its utilities takes time to boot up (cold boot)? In our lab we do not have rack servers we have Dell servers(we have the data) but we need to know for racks in data centers. Please provide answers with proper references. I already googled and I found array of answers without proper references.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because Server Fault is not your research lab.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're asking this, but expect 5-9 minutes for a current generation modern server (HP or Dell) to boot ESXi.

Comment: 5 minutes to get the Hypervisor running sounds about right. Botting the VMs could take *much* longer.